# Functional Abbreviation for Inst Expression in Turing's Paper

Tags: logic, proof, turing

In Turing's 1936 paper [On Computable Numbers Page 30-31](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Erobins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf), and its [Correction Page 1-2](https://www.wolframscience.com/prizes/tm23/images/Turing2.pdf)

For a Turing Machine  ***M***, ***Inst(i,j,k,LEFT,l)*** means that if ***M*** scans symbol ***j*** under m-configuration ***i***, then the symbol on the  square under scanner (with symbol ***j***) is to be replaced by symbol ***k***, and the scanner/header moves one unit ***Left***, and its new m-configuration becomes ***l***.

If:

R(j,x,y) means "In the complete configuration x (of M) the symbol on the square y is j.

I(x,y) means that "In the complete configuration x (of M) the square y is scanned".

K(m,x) means that "In the complete configuration x (of M) the m-configuration is m".

F(x,y) means that "y is the immediate successor of x".

At any stage of the motion of the machine, the number of the scanned
square, the complete sequence of all symbols on the tape, and the
m-configuration will be said to describe the complete configuration at that
stage. The changes of the machine and tape between successive complete
configurations will be called the moves of the machine.

Then, for establishing equivalence between Turing Machine and restricted
Hilbert functional calculus, Turing writes: "***Inst(i,j,k,LEFT,l)*** is to be an abbreviation for:

> (x,y,x',y') **{** (R(j,x,y) & I(x,y) & K(i,x) & F(x,x') & F(y',y)) → ( I(x',y') & R(k,x',y) & K(l,x') & F(y',z)  ∨  [(R(S0,x,z) → R(S0,x',z)) & (R(S1,x,z) → R(S1,x',z)) & ... & (R(SM,x,z) → R(SM,x',z))]) **}**

S0, S1, ..., SM being the symbols ***M*** can print."

I am unable to convince myself of the exact correctness of the above formula w.r.t. to the meaning of ***Inst(i,j,k,LEFT,l)***. More specifically, why do we have the following expression included? What is he trying to *"cover"* by including it?

> ... & F(y',z)  ∨  [(R(S0,x,z) → R(S0,x',z)) & (R(S1,x,z) → R(S1,x',z))
> & ... & (R(SM,x,z) → R(SM,x',z))]) **}**

Comment: It is not clear how this question relates to philosophy and would perhaps be better posed on [Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turing is coding the "instruction table" (page 241).

The standard form of a line in the table is:

> **Qi, Sj, Sk, L** (or **R** or **N**), **Ql**

that means: "the machine is in state **Qi** and is scanning tape with symbol **Sj**. It replaces symbol **Sj** with new symbol **Sk** and moves **L**eft (or **R** or **N**) changing to the new state **Ql**."

The author define a predicate **Inst (Qi, Sj, Sk, L, Ql)** using the previous defined function that you have listed above.

Thus, he uses **I(x,y)** to identify the square **y** of the tape, **R(Sj,x,y)** to identify the symbol written on square **y** of tape, **K(Qi,x)** to identify the "current" configuration **Qi**.

This is the part "**Qi, Sj**" of the line in the table above.

Thus, the first part reads:

> "if the machine **x** is in configuration **Qi** and it is scanning the square **y** of the tape and on this square there is the symbol **Sj**, then ..."

Consequently, the second part of the formula (the consequent of the conditional) will encode the actions to be performed.

First thing, the machine perform a new "step" **x+1** in the computation, changing the symbol written on square **y** to **Sk**:  **R(Sk, x+1, y)**, and the state of the machine is changed to **Ql**, and this is the meaning of **K(Ql,x+1)**.

Finally, the machine moves left to scan the new square **y+1**:  **I(x+1,y+1)** (this is the meaning of using F(x,x') and F(y',y)) and I(x',y')).

---

Now to the puzzling part, that modified in the Corrigendum.

The original paper has:

> **(z) [F(y+1,z) ∨ (R(Sj,x,z) → R(Sk,x+1,z)]**

that reads "if **z** is not the square **y+1** then its content *was* **Sj** and now *is* **Sk**", that sound wrong.

Maybe the intended formula is: **(z) [¬F(y,z) ∨ (R(Sj,x,z) → R(Sk,x+1,z)]** that reads: "if **z** is the square **y** then its content *was* **Sj** and now *is* **Sk**", that is correct.

The new formula, that still needs the universal quantifier **(z)**, is: **(z) (F(y+1,z) ∨ [(R(S0,x,z) → R(S0,x+1,z)) & ...])**, is a sort of "closure condition".

It reads:

> "either **z** is the new square **y+1** or it is left unchanged",

and is a true description of the tape when step **x** of the computation has been performed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your explanation, should it not be, "...that reads "if **z** is not the square **y** (*instead of* **y+1**), then its content was Sj and now is Sk"......" -because y is the immediate successor of y+1?